# python code fails to create correct mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

The following curl command works as expected. It returns the correct mapping but python code returns blank.

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/geotest/
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/geotest/geotest/_mapping -d '{
    "geotest": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point",
                "lat_lon": true,
                "geohash": true
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/geotest/_mapping
{"geotest":{"mappings":{"geotest":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point","lat_lon":true,"geohash":true}}}}}}
```

I expect this python code to be same as above...

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://some_site.com:9200/')

mymapping={"geotest":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point","lat_lon":True,"geohash":True}}}}

es.indices.delete(index = 'geotest')
es.indices.create(index = 'geotest', body = mymapping)

curl -XGET localhost:9200/geotest/_mapping
{"geotest":{"mappings":{}}}
```

Why does python code does not create correct mapping the way curl does?

---

Update:

Using the put_mapping method I am not able to create wikipedia content index.

```
import urllib2
myfile=urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json').read()

import ast
myfile1=ast.literal_eval(myfile)['content']['page']['properties']

import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://some_site.com:9200/')

es.indices.delete(index ='enwiki_todel')
es.indices.create(index ='enwiki_todel')
es.indices.put_mapping(index ='enwiki_todel', doc_type='page', body = myfile1)
```

---

update 2

I tried to keep only content using ast module. And still getting mapper parsing exception.

```
import urllib2
myfile=urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json').read()

import ast
myfile1=ast.literal_eval(myfile)['content']

import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://ec2-52-91-179-95.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9200/')


es.indices.delete(index ='enwiki_todel')
es.indices.create(index ='enwiki_todel')
es.indices.put_mapping(index ='enwiki_todel', doc_type='page', body = myfile1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. If you want to create an index with a mapping in one shot, you need to use the `"mappings": {}` structure in the body of your `create` index call. Like this:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://some_site.com:9200/')

mymapping={"mappings": {"geotest":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point","lat_lon":True,"geohash":True}}}}}
              ^
              |
 enclose your mapping in "mappings"

es.indices.delete(index = 'geotest')
es.indices.create(index = 'geotest', body = mymapping)
```

An alternate solution is to use [put_mapping](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping) after the call to `create` and you'll be able to use the same structure you initially had, i.e. without the `"mappings: {}` structure.

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://some_site.com:9200/')

mymapping={"geotest":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_point","lat_lon":True,"geohash":True}}}}

es.indices.delete(index = 'geotest')
es.indices.create(index = 'geotest')
es.indices.put_mapping(index = 'geotest', body = mymapping)
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. But wikipedia mapping seems to have some issues. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I think `myfile1` is not correct, you need that statement to be like this: `myfile1=ast.literal_eval(myfile)['content']`, i.e. `page` and `properties` need to be left in the file.

Comment: Still getting the mapper parsing exception. Please see the code in updated question.

Comment: Would be nice to also see the mapping exception you're getting.

Comment: If you copy-paste the code mentioned in update 2, aren't you getting this error? RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception')

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in what shows up in the ES log as the Python client will not show exactly what has been returned from ES.