# How to set mapping in es.index in the elasticsearch python client?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have twitter data in json format which I have to index using elastic search. I also have to specify mapping for the data.

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
mapping='''{"mappings": {"_doc": {"properties":.......'''
for i,record in enumerate(data):
    es.index(index='index', doc_type='tweet', id=i, body=record)
```

Where should I specify my mapping?

I read that I can specify the mapping in `es.indices.create`

```
es.indices.create(.......,body=mapping)
```

But then How do I input my record data? What is the difference between es.indices.create, es.index and es.create?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172438/python-code-fails-to-create-correct-mapping/34172536#34172536